# Как вставить записи в две связанные внешним ключом таблицы в одной транзакции?

Tags: sql, oracle, транзакции, constraints

Есть две таблицы, которые имеют друг на друга внешний ключ, который не может быть `NULL`. Каждая таблица имеет первичный ключ в виде AI (*auto increment*).

При попытке вставки в первую таблицу, нужно указать ID второй таблицы, а чтобы вставить во вторую таблицу, нужно указать ID первой. Такой вот замкнутый круг. Естественно, ошибка при валидации внешнего ключа, мол не может при вставке найти таблицу первую (или вторую), *ведь ее еще нет*.

Возможно ли вообще выполнить такую вставку? Или придется отключать временно внешний ключ, а потом обновить строку?

Хотелось бы более красивое решение.

Comment: Задача на воображение? :) приведите пример, каким запросом или запросами вы хотите выполнить вставку, и что именно не получается. [Вот это](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/insert-records/) случаем не в тему?

Comment: А для чего вам это нужно? Может быть посмотреть в сторону - верен ли дизайн.

Comment: Убарал метку C#, так как не вижу связи с вопросом. Вы хоть на ассемблере напишите, поведение описанное в вопросе не изменится.

Comment: *Есть две таблицы, которые имеют друг на друга внешний ключ, который не может быть NULL. Каждая таблица имеет первичный ключ в виде AI (auto increment).* Полный, точный некастрированный CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц - в студию (добавить в текст вопроса). Ибо если существующее точно описывает реальное положение дел - у Вас неверна структура хранения данных. Впрочем, в Oracle, у которого есть отложенная проверка констрейнтов - решаемо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отложите проверку ограничений до конца транзакции с [DEFERRABLE Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE). Вот так:

```
create table t1 (
    id int generated as identity primary key, 
    t2id int not null deferrable initially deferred)
/
create table t2 (
    id int generated as identity primary key, 
    t1id int not null references t1 (id))
/
alter table t1 modify t2id references t2 (id); 
/
<<my>> declare
    t1id int;
    t2id int;
begin 
    insert into t1 (t2id) values (null) returning id into my.t1id;
    insert into t2 (t1id) values (t1id) returning id into my.t2id;
    update t1 set t2id=my.t2id where id = my.t1id; 
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

commit;

Commit complete.
```

Результат:

```
select * from t1 cross join t2
/
      ID       T2ID       ID       T1ID
-------- ---------- -------- ----------
       1          1        1          1
```